# How jmeter works on HTTPS without using certificates

Tags: jmeter, certificate, ssl-certificate

I am working on HTTPS calls in jmeter. When I started to do the configuration I took help of stackoverflow. Surprisingly I found all I have to do is to change protocol from HTTP to HTTPS and it actually worked. Which makes me wonder how jmeter bypasses the certificate without any configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Some sites use simple mode of [HTTPS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) which doesn't require client installation

> SSL and TLS encryption can be configured in two modes: simple and mutual. **In simple mode, authentication is only performed by the server**. The mutual version requires the user to install a personal client certificate in the web browser for user authentication.

Answer (score 1):

As per [1.2.4 SSL Encryption](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#opt_ssl) chapter:

> **The JMeter HTTP samplers are configured to accept all certificates, whether trusted or not, regardless of validity periods, etc.** This is to allow the maximum flexibility in testing servers.
>
> If the server requires a [client certificate](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates/), this can be provided.